# How to set a JButton as default Button in java?

Tags: java, swing

Problem: I have a look and feel already defined for default buttons.
Now I have written a JButton which I want to be set as a default button. How do I make it a default button?
Answers are appreciated in advance.Below is a snippet of my code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
button = new JButton(IConfigConstants.GENERATE_BUTTON_TEXT);
boolean enable = node.isComplete();
button.setEnabled(enable);
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.add(button);
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Probably needs button.setDefaultCapable(true);

Comment: @mwarren Perhaps, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JButton.html#setDefaultCapable%28boolean%29) it’s true by default.

Comment: @VGR You are totally correct, the documentation also says ' The default value of the defaultCapable property is true unless otherwise specified by the look and feel.' So it might be false.

Answer (score 0):

To set a button as a default button (i.e to be selected/focused by default on application startup), you can do:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(yourButton);
```

Comment: The line of code in your answer already appears in the question, so how does it solve the problem?

Comment: @Abra I guess he was kinda confused that that was the answer right there, so I simplified it by giving it as an answer. Someone who will come looking for the same thing will see the question as unanswered and just go back as opposed to when they see even a single answer, they'll try it out and it works, which is the whole point. What I mean is, people look for answers in the answer section, not in the questions. Thanks